# Error compiling scss after upgrade to Angular 11

Tags: angular, npm, sass

I'm currently on working on upgrading an Angular application to v11.2.11. After running
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
ng update @angular/material
and resolving some issues with typescript v4, I get this error. It appears to be tied to some dependency, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

I have, somehow, managed to get a version of it working via some strange ordering of installs that I can't seem to reproduce.

```
Error: ./src/assets/styles/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'comma' of undefined
    at <project_root>\src\assets\styles\styles.scss:17710:1
    at Placeholder.prefixeds (<project_root>\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\selector.js:68:28)
    at Placeholder.add (<project_root>\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\selector.js:132:26)
    at Placeholder.process (<project_root>\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\prefixer.js:128:16)
    at <project_root>\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\processor.js:83:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at <project_root>\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\processor.js:82:42
    at <project_root>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:115:18
    at <project_root>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:74:18
    at Root.each (<project_root>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:60:16)
    at Root.walk (<project_root>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:71:17)
    at Root.walkRules (<project_root>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:113:19)
    at Processor.add (<project_root>\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\processor.js:79:9)
    at OnceExit (<project_root>\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:129:32)
    at LazyResult.runAsync (<project_root>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:388:19)
    at async Object.loader (<project_root>\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:95:14)
    at <project_root>\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at <project_root>\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at <project_root>\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (<project_root>\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.loader (<project_root>\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:104:7)
```

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -c local",
    "build": "ng build",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.15.3",
    "ag-charts-angular": "3.1.0",
    "ag-charts-community": "3.1.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "25.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "25.1.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "25.1.0",
    "auth0-js": "9.11.3",
    "component": "1.1.0",
    "esprima": "4.0.1",
    "jspdf": "1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "3.2.11",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.3",
    "swagger-ui": "3.45.1",
    "tslib": "2.0.0",
    "xmlbuilder": "14.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.10",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/jspdf": "1.3.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "12.11.1",
    "bulma": "0.7.5",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.0",
    "husky": "6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.0",
    "karma": "6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "1.19.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get the build to pass consistently by downgrading @angular-devkit/build-angular to v10, but I don't understand why that worked.

Comment: can you try deleting node_modules directory and rerunning  npm install

Comment: I have done that several times. I repulled the repo and re-ran it in a new directory too.